# changing styles inside ng-repeat depending on values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to add the class `border-fat-bottom` to my td's every time the `property` value change

This is my data

```
 vm.doubleBookings: [
    {
        "_id": "AA001",
        "property": "ATL-406",
        "name": "Torben Tenant"
    },
    {
        "_id": "AA002",
        "property": "ATL-406",
        "name": "whatever"
    },
    {
        "_id": "AA004",
        "property": "WAT-806",
        "name": "Torben Tenant"
    },
    {
        "_id": "AA005",
        "property": "WAT-806",
        "name": "whatever"
    },
    {
        "_id": "AA006",
        "property": "WAT-806",
        "name": "whatever"
    },
    {
        "_id": "AA007",
        "property": "ANA-202",
        "name": "whatever"
    }
    {
        "_id": "AA007",
        "property": "ZOK-440",
        "name": "whatever"
    }
]
```

This is my ng-repeat

```
 <tr ng-repeat="bookings in vm.doubleBookings" class="start-text">
    <td class="border-thin-top">{{ bookings._id}}</td>
    <td class="border-thin-top">{{ bookings.property }}</td>
    <td class="border-thin-top">{{ bookings.name }}</td>
</tr>
```

so...

`ATL-406` would have one normal row and one with fat-bottom

`WAT-806` would have two normal rows and one with fat-bottom

`ANA-202` would have one with fat-bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr ng-repeat="booking in vm.doubleBookings" class="start-text" 
    ng-class="{'fat-bottom': !$last && booking.property !== vm.doubleBookings[$index + 1].property}">
```

Comment: JB that was such an elegant and simple solution. I had no idea you could still access the `vm.doubleBookings´ like that. I guess you can pretty much code what ever you want in those ng elements.  Thanks to you our double bookings list now look like this :-)   https://db.tt/IQ1UswVimC